# How can I make the width of the caption match that of the listing?

Tags: listings, captions, width

How can I fix the captions width to match the listing? As in the picture below:
[image]

Code is here:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\definecolor{eclipseBlue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseGreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{eclipsePurple}{RGB}{127,0,85}


\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}


\lstset
{
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % Global Code Style
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{eclipseGreen},
    numbers=left, % show line numbers at the left
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily, % style of the line numbers
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!7},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[title=Test]
Code
a
b
b
c
c
d
s
we
wds
s
dsd
sd
sd
sd
gasdg
d
g

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should keep into account the `\fboxsep` padding. I suggest also to add a black border, for uniformity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}% commented for the example
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{calc}
\definecolor{eclipseBlue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseGreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{eclipsePurple}{RGB}{127,0,85}


\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{#1#2#3}}%
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}


\lstset{
  frame=single,
  framesep=\fboxsep,
  framerule=\fboxrule,
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
  xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % Global Code Style
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{eclipseGreen},
  numbers=left, % show line numbers at the left
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily, % style of the line numbers
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!7},
  tabsize=2,
  columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[title=Test]
Code
a
b
b
c
c
d
s
we
wds
s
dsd
sd
sd
sd
gasdg
d
g

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]